# How can I remove bcdedit's GRUB completely?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair

I added  GRUB to my Ubuntu installation's disk by `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`.

Then, I removed Ubuntu from my disk and deleted the "ubuntu" file in the EFI.

Every time I boot my computer, I get a message: `fail to open EFI....` and then my computer boots into Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you want:

- You can use the same `bcdedit` command in Windows, but instead of `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`, you can specify `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`.
- You can use the [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) program in Windows to manage the EFI boot entries in a GUI way. This is likely to be less error-prone that `bcdedit`. Move the Windows entry to the top of the list and/or delete the Ubuntu entry.
- You can boot an Ubuntu live disk and use `efibootmgr` to delete the Ubuntu entry and/or move the Windows entry to the top of the list. Type `sudo efibootmgr` (or `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see more details) to see the list of options; then use the `-b #### -B` option to delete one, or `-o ####[,####[,...]]` to change the boot order. (`####` is a four-digit hexadecimal number associated with a boot entry.) Type `man efibootmgr` for more documentation on this command.
- Many EFIs provide a way to manage boot entries in their own user interfaces. Details vary greatly from one system to another, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to fix this from  Windows 8/10 is using admin command prompt:

```
bcdboot c:\windows
```

To remove remnants of grub completely you have to clean up EFI system partition(ESP). This can be done easily using [Dual-boot Repair 10](https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html) as it mapps ESP automatically to drive Z:(or another free drive letter). Use for example "Backup BCD" dialog to browse z:\EFI and delete "ubuntu" folder.