# Delete Ubuntu with separate efi

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, uninstall, bootloader, grub-efi

I first had Windows 10 installed with EFI partition, I later installed Ubuntu and created a separate EFI partition for its bootloader. Now I want to delete Ubuntu. Can I directly delete the EFI partition and the volume(in which Ubuntu was installed), this wouldn't affect the windows bootloader, right?

Comment: Did Ubuntu install to the ESP you created or into the Windows ESP? Make sure default boot of system is to Windows or else you have issues as UEFI has default boot & ESP - efi system partition only has part of grub. Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was able to do this in the following steps:-
(I did create recovery drive just in case I needed it)

**1.** Using Bios I changed boot priority from "ubuntu->windows boot loader" to "windows boot loader->ubuntu" (Most Important)

**2.** I deleted the Ubuntu volume and swap partitions using disk management(in Windows).

**3.** I deleted the Ubuntu/GRUB EFI partition using "*diskpart*" in cmd. (using command *delete partition override*)

**4.** Mounted the original EFI partition using "*diskpart*", assigned a letter to it (lets say Z) the removed the ubuntu bootloader from it. Using following commands:-

*z:*

*cd efi*

*rd ubuntu /s*

**5.** At last I deleted ubuntu efi boot option using Hasleo EasyUEFI (GUI Software).( https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html ). Got help from here [How can I remove bcdedit's GRUB completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722366/how-can-i-remove-bcdedits-grub-completely)